# Overlay of DIVs not working once Form tags are added

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm at an impasse and hoping for some help. I'm needing to overlay what amounts to a smart messagebox inside a Webforms project. I'll need to pass data both to and from this 'window'. In order to facilitate that, I've opted to use overlaid DIVs within the page.

A simple app has been created which overlays two DIV segments by changing the DIV's styles. All works well until a Form is added to the mix. (I need a Form in order to run the actual page.)

So, here's the problem. Once the Form tag is added, the overlay no longer works. It will 'flash' the overlay, but immediately return to the original style (ie, no overlay)

Code for this simple example is contained below. Note that removing the form allows the overlay to run as advertised. Adding it back...not so much.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="CovidScan.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="text">
  <h2>This is the overlay</h2>
  <button onclick="off()">Turn off overlay</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
  <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>
</form>

<script>
    function on() {
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.background = "green";
    }

    function off() {
       document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";    
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: form buttons default to "submit" in most browsers - and you give it no type so it guesses that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Yup the button is submitting the form, thus the page refreshes and it gives the "flash effect"

Comment: by practice I would always specify a `type` attribute on buttons